# How to move a directory in Linux onto a separate partition

Tags: linux, rhel

I would like to move a directory say, /log onto a separate file system in the same hard disk (only one volume) and set a disk space say 10GB. I followed this post that does the same but onto a new disk. https://serverfault.com/questions/1010355/mount-a-directory-on-a-new-partition-or-disk

```
mkdir /mnt/temp
mount /dev/sda /mnt/temp
cp -pr /lib/* /mnt/temp
umount /mnt/temp
mount /dev/sda /lib
umount /dev/sda
mount /dev/sda
```

are these commands correct? How do I allocate space 10GB? Finally, how do I confirm that the lib directory was moved to a new partition?

Comment: No, those commands are not correct. The second command attempts to mount the whole disk as a single filesystem. If there's only one disk, that implies it's the disk you are already using, and if the disk is partitioned (as is likely), using `/dev/sda` for a filesystem would overwrite the partition table and any existing filesystems, causing data loss and system crash. However, the `mount` command will detect that `/dev/sda` doesn't seem to contain a valid filesystem and will harmlessly stop with an error message.

Comment: To successfully plan your operation, you would have to see the output of e.g. `fdisk -l /dev/sda` to a) verify there is free space on the disk that has not yet been allocated to existing partions (that you wish to keep), and b) identify the next free partition number. I would also note that moving the `/lib` directory around is especially tricky since it contains the dynamic linker/loader that is used by essentially **all** normal programs: if it becomes inaccessible for any reason, only the running shells' internal commands and fully statically linked programs will work.

Comment: Only one disk that has all the space 75GB. Unpartitioned space /dev/xvda: 0 B, 0 bytes, 0 sectors

Comment: You would partition the disk before you do any of this, and make the partition the size you want, obviously up to what the entire disk provides. Is there a reason you are not planning to use the entire disk for this?

Comment: If you don't have any unallocated space on the disk, you cannot create any new partitions on that disk. However, the fact that your disk is named `/dev/xvda` indicates it is part of a virtual machine, which means it might be possible to expand the virtual disk from the host system. You would have to get that done first, then use the added space to create a new partition (e.g. `/dev/xvda3`), initialize a filesystem within that partition, and only then you could mount it.

Comment: Using "fdisk /dev/xvda1" command I created a new extended partition with a new partition size.
It now shows a new partition that is, /dev/xvda1p3
How do I use this partition for a specific directory?

Comment: Simply `mount /dev/xvda1p3 /mnt/tmp`

Comment: special device /dev/xvda1p3 does not exist.

Comment: Device is there. Command (m for help): i
Partition number (2,3, default 3): 3

         Device: /dev/xvda1p3

Comment: Maybe examine `/var/log/messages` for what devices you have where. If you just created the partition or inserted a removable disk, the message should be among the latest few.

Comment: the log doesn't have anything about xvda1p3.